# extract rows from one csv file based on column information in the other csv

Tags: csv, awk

I have 2 csv files. I want the information from column 1 of from file 1 to be used to extract rows from the other csv file.
My file1.csv has names arranged in columns :

```
ENSG00000102977
ENSG00000100823
ENSG00000149311
ENSG00000175054
ENSG00000085224
ENSG00000178999
ENSG00000197299
ENSG00000139618
ENSG00000105173
ENSG00000175305
ENSG00000166226
ENSG00000163468
ENSG00000115484
ENSG00000150753
ENSG00000146731
```

and the 2nd csv file has the names along with the corresponding values arranged in rows.

```
ENSG00000102977 1083.82334384253    1824.50639384557    1962.86064714976    1367.60568624972
```

I wrote an awk script

```
`awk 'FNR == NR{f1[$1];next} $1 in f2 {print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5 $NF}' FS="," file1.csv  FS="," file2.csv`
```

but it returns without any output or error.
Kindly guide me as to where I am wrong. Its a bit puzzling since there is no error.

Comment: What is expected output? Also why is all of file2 content showing in same line where you mentioned `corresponding values arranged in rows`

Comment: Your first block initializes array `f1` but in the second you use the `f2` (empty) array. Fix this and things should be better.

Answer (score 2):

Try `grep`'s option -f - read pattern from a file.

```
grep -f fileWithPatterns.csv fileToExtractFrom.csv
```